# Editing xml data

Tags: xml, openstreetmap

I have an .osm file which is basically an xml. I would like to remove all the elements in it which do not have a "highway" tag in it. The highway tag is an simple xml attribute. It's quite a large file and it's not easy to do manually.
What would be a quick way to remove all the elements?

Comment: Need to see sample of XML.  Probably need to use XML Linq with a 'WHERE' != "highway".

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? By dropping all elements that don't have a highway tag you will also loose all geometry information. Because in order to obtain way geometries you have to keep all nodes that are referenced by the ways you are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probally want to make use of [osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis), [osmfilter](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter), ... tools that understand the OSM fileformat and it's semantic.